# wait after the page has loaded after I use document.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going through a set of pages on a website and need to do something on the webpage. I am currently running my script in Chrome Dev Console to figure out how to get it to work.

```
let items = [134, 147]
for (let item of items) {
let url = `https://example.com/catalog/items/${item}`
this.document.location = url;
//Do some modifications on the page using Jquery and press Submit - this reloads the page. After the reload, move to the next page. 
}
```

I need help on 2 things:

1. How do I do my modifications after the page has loaded?
2. After doing my modifications and pressing Submit, I need to wait for the current page to reload before moving to the next page in the list. How do I do that?

Comment: It's really `window.location =` or just plain `location = `, as `window` is implicit. But you would just do the assignment when the Event occurs.

Comment: In general, you can't directly modify a page from a previous page. When you set `location`, the current page completely unloads and all scripts end, then the next page is loaded.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks, I understand this. But how do I achieve my task of visiting a set of URLs and doing some work on each one of them. Is that not possible at all through JS or Jquery?

Comment: Use a variable in the query string to keep track of what url you are on, maybe?

Comment: you can achieve that but your question is not clear.. what will be your next page url.. and

Comment: @ash, please refer to line 3 of my code - I have a template literal string which is updated each time through the loop. I am navigating different items on a catalog - the only change is the item_id - so, I used a for loop to produce the URL string each time.

Comment: One thing I'm not really clear on is how you make the changes stick. You load a page, makes some changes programmatically... And then what? How are those changes saved? If these pages are all served by the same server and you're pushing those changes back to that server, it stands to reason that you could have the server include the necessary one-shot code to move to the next page. In fact, you could just make the changes on the server and skip loading them entirely.

Comment: store your item_id in local and session storage and get it back after page reload.

Comment: @Ouroborus I do not have access to the server code. we are using an external helpdesk app which does not support API operations for updating values in a dropdown. Hence, we are currently doing it manually to update it - instead I want to automate. Once I click on save, it is saved in the server.

Comment: Oh, got it. A technique I've used before, for exactly that situation, is to load a page of that app and then use JS in the console to replace the entire body content with an iframe and the automation script. The script would load and manipulate the pages via the iframe. Using this technique allows your script to hang around between the page loads while also getting around things like CORS.

Comment: @Ouroborus thanks a lot for this pointer. Let me explore this. Can you please post this in the answer with some more details if you can and I would mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to DOMContentLoaded to know the page has loaded and if you are reloading the 'same' page, you could use session storage, if it is the same domain, etc.